# Terraform Throttling Route53

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Did anyone experienced issues with Terraform being throttled when using it with AWS Route53 records and being VERY slow?

I have enabled DEBUG mode and getting this:

```
2018-11-30T14:35:08.467Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.36.0_x4: 2018/11/30 14:35:08 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] <?xml  version="1.0"?>
2018-11-30T14:35:08.467Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider aws_v1.36.0_x4: <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-04-01/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>Throttling</Code><Message>Rate exceeded</Message></Error><RequestId>REQUEST_ID</RequestId></ErrorResponse>
2018-11-30T14:35:08.518Z [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v1.36.0_x4: 2018/11/30 14:35:08 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response route53/ListResourceRecordSets failed, will retry, error Throttling: Rate exceeded
```

Terraform takes >1h just to do simple Plan, something which normally takes <5 mins.

My infrastructure is organized like this:

alb.tf:

```
module "ALB" 
{ source = "modules/alb" }
```

modules/alb/alb.tf:

```
resource "aws_alb" "ALB" 
{ name = "alb" 
subnets = var.subnets ...
}
```

modules/alb/dns.tf

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "r53" {
  count     =  "${length(var.cnames_generic)}"
  zone_id   = "HOSTED_ZONE_ID"
  name      = "${element(var.cnames_generic_dns, count.index)}.${var.environment}.${var.domain}"
  type      = "A"

  alias {
    name    = "dualstack.${aws_alb.ALB.dns_name}"
    zone_id = "${aws_alb.ALB.zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}
```

modules/alb/variables.tf:

```
variable "cnames_generic_dns" {
  type = "list"
  default = [
    "hostname1",
    "hostname2",
    "hostname3",
    "hostname4",
    "hostname5",
    "hostname6",
    "hostname7",
     ...
    "hostname25"
      ]
}
```

So I am using modules to configure Terraform, and inside modules there are resources (ALB, DNS..).

However, looks like Terraform is describing every single DNS Resource (CNAME and A records, which I have ~1000) in a HostedZone which is causing it to Throttle?

```
Terraform v0.10.7
Terraform AWS provider version = "~> 1.36.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

that's a lot of DNS records! And partly the reason why the AWS API is throttling you.

First, I'd recommend upgrading your AWS provider. v1.36 is fairly old and there have been more than a few bug fixes since.

*(Next, but not absolutely necessary, is to use TF v0.11.x if possible.)*

In your AWS Provider block, increase [`max_retries`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#max_retries) to at least 10 and experiment with higher values.

Then, use Terraform's [`--parallelism`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#parallelism-n) flag to limit TF's concurrency rate. Try setting that to 5 for starters.

Last, enable [Terraform's debug mode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html) to see if it gives you any more useful info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks KJH, tried with max_retries and parallelism but it didn't helped. What helped is to leave it running as is, delete and recreate records again. I will reply in more details

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by performing the following actions:

- since we re-structured DNS records by adding one resource and then variables / iterate through them, this probably caused Terraform to query constantly all DNS records
- we decided to leave Terraform to finish refresh (took 4h and lots of throttling)
- manually deleted DNS records from R53 for the Workspace which we were doing this
- commenting out Terraform DNS resources so let it also delete from state files
- uncommenting Terraform DNS and re-run it again so it created them again
- run Terraform plan went fine again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like throttling with Terraform AWS Route53 is completely resolved after upgrading to newer AWS provider. We have updated TF AWS provider to 1.54.0 like this in our init.tf :

```
version = "~> 1.54.0"
```

Here are more details about the issue and suggestions from Hashicorp engineers:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7056